# Fastest way of picking apart a String in java

Tags: java, string, performance

Program takes many commands, then needs to break the command down into parts so that it is usable, currently have a very crude version of this. Looking to make it as fast as possible though. Here is bits of code so that this is understandable:

```
String keyCommands[] = new String[]{"me","a","new","word","text", "document","notepad"};
String optional[] = new String[]{"hi","Hey","Please","Do you mind"};
String keyWords[] = new String[]{"open","opening","open up","log in", "login","email","quit"};
```

If I was to type something like: "hey please open up a new notepad"
what is the fastest way to peel off things from the optional array from the string, then split the string into key commands and key words.

Bonus, but not needed: If like in the example it was given open up, how could I get it to just record that means open (remember, all these arrays are MUCH bigger in my program, so just checking to see if the word open is in it will only work with this specific case).

I hope this question is not to confusing. Efficiency is important to me for this program.

Comment: Do you need to peel off the optional stuff? Why don't you just ignore them and focus on the keywords you are looking for?

Comment: You'll probably need to create a parser for the command string. It's not as simple as replacing and splitting strings.

Comment: @ortang Its not 100% needed, although preferred as I will be doing other stuff with the optional text that was typed. Still unsure of fastest way of finding the keywords though. If the keyword string is 2+ words and in the middle of the other string I find it had to efficiently find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big are the sets of keywords/commands which you are working with? How big are the input strings? And how many times do you need to do this a second? You said that performance is important to you, but it may be that performance won't matter as much as you think.

Would it be possible to interpret **anything** which is not a command or keyword as "optional" ? That would simplify the problem.

If you really want to know the *absolute fastest way* to process input strings in the manner you describe, first of all, it would be best if the input comes in as a `char` array, not as a `String`. Depending on where you are reading the input from, you may be able to read `char`s (or `byte`s if that is more appropriate in your situation) directly into a preallocated array, process it, then reuse the array when reading the next input. You'll need to keep an index into the array which indicates where the input ends.

Next, assuming you really want *absolute maximum* performance, the next step would probably be to hand-code a DFA (state machine) which makes a single pass over the input, picking out the parts you need and copying them. This would be similar to what DFA-based regex engines do internally, but with careful hand-coding, you *should* be able to come up with something faster than what a regex engine can do.

For similar results, with a lot less work, make one regex which is the union of all your commands/keywords/optional phrases. The regex should start with a `\G` to anchor it at the end of the previous match. (You can look up information on the use of the `\G` anchor in regexes.) Since you want high performance, make sure to reuse a single `Pattern` object. In a loop, repeatedly match that against the input string to pull out the pieces. Then, do membership tests in a couple of sets to determine whether the match was a command, a keyword, or something else.

You can experiment to see whether membership testing will be faster with a hash set, or something else. Actually, a trie would probably be fastest, but I don't think there is any standard class in the Java plaform for a search trie.

If you code up your own trie class, as a bonus, you could make it combine the keyword set **and** the command set, and it could identify which one a given string was.

If you do write your own trie, I'd like to see it!

**ANOTHER IDEA,** again assuming that you want absurd levels of performance, would be to use perfect hashing for the membership test, since your keyword/command sets are known in advance.

Comment: Keywords/commands atm are only about 500 elements long, however it will be LARGELY expanding over the next few months. Unfortunately I can not consider anything that isnt a command/keyword as optional(Fairly large explanation to as to why). Thank you for your great answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Well to split a sentence where words are separated by space, you can try something like:

```
String input = "Hey please open up a new notepad";
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
```

Now words has the following structure:

```
words[0] = "Hey", words[1] = "please", words[2] = "open" and so on.
```

Also check out [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) in Java if you have complex statements so that you can identify patterns in your input statements and execute appropriate commands.

Comment: But it does not split it into "Hey please" which is what is in the optional array, therefore would be had to peel off like this.

Comment: So you want "Hey please" to be considered one token?

Comment: Yes, and open up as another token, and a new notepad as a 3rd. basically splitting it into 3 parts.

Comment: Well then once you have them splitted based on my logic above, you can search for particular commands and see if the next word in the splitted list contains the second word of the command or not.  A better solution would be to have terse commands, as gestures like "Hey" and "Please" don't matter. You can simply search for your Keywords and execute appropriate Commands. Also check out Command Pattern as I think you'll need that in order to write modular and extensible code in this particular type of project.

Answer (score 0):

> Efficiency is important to me for this program.

That may be so.  However, the chances are that the efficiency of the argument parsing is not significant.

- It happens only once during the execution of the program.
- Unless it is exceedingly complicated (or very poorly designed) the parsing probably takes much less time than the time taken to bootstrap the JVM, load your application and various other "warmup" overheads.  JVM-based applications, simply don't launch quickly.

So I'm going to suggest that *put off* trying to make the command argument parsing / processing until you have the rest of your application coded, tested and running.  Then do the following:

1. Benchmark the application runs doing a typical task.  If it is "fast enough" then you are done.
2. Profile the application using a CPU performance profiler to work out the performance hotspots where "most" of the time goes.
3. Identify a potential optimization for one of the biggest hotspots, and code it and test it, and then rerun your benchmark to see if you have *actually* improved performance.
4. Repeat from step 2 ... until you run out of worthwhile hotspots and potential optimizations.

I expect that you will find that despite your intuition, your argument processing never makes it onto "the front page" of performance hotspots.  That means that the payoff for optimizing that code won't be large enough to justify the effort.

---

The other thing is that what you seem to be doing is some kind of natural language processing.  If you are doing language processing "for real" (as distinct to something simple and heuristic), then this is a really difficult and technical area.  You would be better off looking for an existing library and using that ... and relying on the library implementors to deal with efficiency concerns.

Comment: I am doing it for real, don't suppose you would be able to point me to any library inparticular? I looked but was unable to find one.

Comment: Well the library I see most often mentioned is Stanford NLP.  http://nlp.stanford.edu/